# My shared (Gradle) library is not being read correctly...Artifactory Maven Pom file not publishing exclusions is suspected cause

Tags: maven, gradle, publish, artifactory

I have a number of shared libraries that I am publishing to Artifactory using Gradle (with Jenkins) and referencing from other projects. When a dependent project pulls down the library from Artifactory, it fails tests relevant to that library (can't find classes etc.). If I locally install the library in my Maven repository, everything works fine, so I can only assume there is a crucial difference between the Artifactory package and the Gradle 'install' task package.

I have compared the two packages, and the `pom` seems to be causing the problem (the Artifactory `pom` file causes my Maven repository build to fail when I manually paste it in). The key difference I can see between these is that the Artifactory `pom` does not include dependency exclusions:

*Local Maven repo pom using 'install' Gradle task:*

```
<groupId>blah</groupId>
<artifactId>some-library</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
         <scope>compile</scope>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <artifactId> ......etc
```

*Artifactory published pom:*

```
<groupId>blah</groupId>
<artifactId>some-library</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.next.dependency</groupId>
```

I have tried adding a script to introduce these exclusions (as suggested [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/maven-publish-plugin-does-not-add-excludes-to-generated-pom/7297/9)), but couldn't get the script to work.

Does anyone have any other suggestions for how to get these exclusions to appear? Or am I down the wrong track and could it be something else entirely?

I've been playing about with this for days now so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks all!

Comment: Is it a problem with transitive dependency or this one? Does your dependency have snapshot version?

Answer (score 1):

I've now progressed the problem further and found the problem wasn't where I thought it was - so I have a half answer!

The lack of exclusions turned out to be a red herring. Another part of our setup which I didn't mention, was that I have extricated out common gradle config into a separate module. This has some dependencies in it that are common to each module. The library module mentioned in the question above has some additional dependencies, and these were not being captured in the resulting pom.

This appears to be an outstanding issue with the Artifactory plugin, which I have chased up [here](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/GAP-156)